# Send a array with Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

Trying to send an array from:

```
<select name='galaddvenn[]'  class='sel_add vl hidden' multiple='multiple'>
<option value='53'>name1</option>
<option value='352'>name2</option>
<option value='632'>name3</option>
<option value='543'>name4</option>..etc
</select>
```

...to/from Jquery with:

```
var ar = $("select#galaddvenn").serialize();

        j.ajax({
        data: ({ar : ar}), //tried with 'ar':ar
        dataType: "html",
        type:"post",
        url: "/ajax_gal_addvenn.php",
        cache: false,
```

....etc
to PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['ar'])){
$ar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ar']);
var_dump($ar);
```

Gives me: bool(false) :(

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) gets a complete POST string by itself, so it'll be formatted like this:

```
galaddvenn=53&galaddvenn=352&galaddvenn=632
```

So your call should look like this:

```
j.ajax({
    data: ar,
    dataType: "html",
    type:"post",
    url: "/ajax_gal_addvenn.php",
    cache: false
});
```

Then on the PHP side, you're looking for `$_POST['galaddvenn']` instead.

[You can test the output here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8nhZj/).

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` expects a string. You cannot use it on your array. Check the [docs](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) for further information. You should use a loop to do this:

```
foreach ($_POST['ar'] as $key => $element) {
    $_POST['ar'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($element);
}
```

If you get errors like this, you should test your incoming data before manipulating them (e.g. use `var_dump()` before applying `mysql_real_escape_string()`).

Comment: @Thundercat - It is essentially empty, or rather a useless string, see my answer :)

Comment: @Thundercat: The reason is that you should look for `$_POST['galaddvenn']` like suggested by Nick Craver. Use `var_dump()` on `$_POST` to see why ;)